# Cross-compilation of arch linux for Arm on Ubuntu 32bit

Tags: arch-linux, raspberry-pi, arm, cross-compilation, arch-arm

I wanted to cross-compile arch linux for arm for raspberry pi b+. I am using Distcc tool on ubuntu 32 bit. I followed every step mentioned [here](https://archlinuxarm.org/wiki/Distcc_Cross-Compiling). to building cross-tool chain, it is asking me various libraries in `/home/your_user/cross/bin.` so I have to download manually all libraries. now, I can't find gcc-6.3.1.tar.gz. I went through gcc website I got gcc-6-3-0.tar.gz. I stuck up badly. and it is annoying to download various library.   please help me out here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

GCC 6.3.1 is not an official release; but you can still get an archive of the source code by finding out at which point it was "released", such as with the [Arch Linux Package List](https://www.archlinux.org/packages/core/x86_64/gcc/), where you can look into the history of the package. Its PKGBUILD will tell you the version and the commit hash, which you can then look up in the GCC git. Here's the Snapshot link for GCC 6.3.1: https://gcc.gnu.org/git/?p=gcc.git;a=snapshot;h=4ca53f06ff7d346ef8021a23108f23a5406a0417;sf=tgz - rename to gcc-6.3.1.tar.gz and you're good to go.